# sql group by per month and year with one row id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with month, year and an id like this.

```
+-------+-----------+-----
| month |    year   |  id
+-------+-----------+-----
| 1     |  2016     |1
+-------+-----------+-----
| 2     | 2016      |2
+-------+-----------+-----
| 2     | 2016      |3
+-------+-----------+-----
```

and i want a sql query that give me only one row per month/year with the id if is single or the id null if there are multiple row for that month year.

in the case above

```
+-------+-----------+-----
| month |    year   |  id
+-------+-----------+-----
| 1     |  2016     |1
+-------+-----------+-----
| 2     | 2016      |null
+-------+-----------+-----
```

how can i do this query qith sql server 2012?

Comment: Can you add two equal rows, both (3, 2016, 4), and adjust the expected result?

Comment: jarlh, the correct result i want correspond to the Gordon Linodd's answer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and `case`:

```
select month, year,
       (case when min(id) = max(id) then min(id) end) as id
from t
group by month, year;
```

Note:  `month` and `year` are bad names for columns, because they are reserved words.  If these are really the names of your columns, you will need to escape them.

Comment: i think user is expecting null value if there are mutiple values...only one row per month/year with the id if is single or the id null if there are multiple row for that month year

Comment: If same id is found twice for a year/month, it will be returned. As I understand it NULL is expected in that case.

Comment: @jarlh . . . Interesting.  I interpreted the question as the id having a "single value" in the rows.  The question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**only one row per month/year with the id if is single or the id null if there are multiple row for that month year

```
with cte
    as
    (
    select row_number() over (partition by month,year  order by (Select 1)) as rn,
    month,year,id
    from
    table
    )
    select 
    case when rn>1 then null else id end as 'id',
    month,
    year
    from
    cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed the part about the NULL in the OP, here's an adjusted query

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    Month INT NOT NULL,
    Year INT NOT NULL,
    Id INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
   (2016, 1, 1)
   ,(2016, 2, 2)
   ,(2016, 2, 3)

SELECT 
    Month
   ,Year
   ,CASE WHEN COUNT(Id) > 1 THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(Id) END AS [Id]
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY Month, Year
```

http://rextester.com/FWVHI57098

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY` that counts each month and year's number of rows. Have a `case` expression that if one row, returns it using min(id), otherwise (more than 1 row) returns null.

```
select month, year, case when count(*) = 1 then min(id) else null end
from tablename
group by month, year;
```